# Send mail with special characteres and Indy

Tags: freepascal, lazarus, indy10

I try to send email. In the body of TIdMessage I have a string with 'ménage'. After the IdMessage is send via an IdSMTP. If my program run under Windows (compiled with Lazarus), no problem. If my program is compiled and run under Linux, I get 'propretÃ©'. I have try meDefault, meMIME and mePlainText for the encoding property of the IdMessage, nothing to do I allways have the error.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try to use wireshark to see what (encoding) is actually sent over the wire.

Comment: `propretÃ©` is the UTF-8 encoded form of `propreté` being misinterpreted as Latin-1. Are you specifying a UTF-8 `Charset` on the email? Please show your actual code that is setting up the `TIdMessage`. Also, which version of FreePascal/Lazarus are you using? If you are using FPC 3.0+, it would better to compile Indy in `{$MODE DelphiUnicode}` or `{$MODESWITCH UnicodeStrings}` mode to enable better Unicode string handling

Answer (score 0):

I am with Lazarus 2.0.6 on Raspberry PI. I have changed a little bit my code, now the special characteres are ok inside the message, but not in the subject of my email!!??

```
IdMessage.Clear;
IdMessage.IsEncoded := True; 
IdMessage.ContentTransferEncoding := 'base64'; 
IdMessage.Encoding := meMime; 
IdMessage.ContentType := 'text/plain'; 
IdMessage.Charset := 'UTF-8'; 
IdMessage.Date:=Now; //Date de l'envoi du message 
IdMessage.Subject:='Propreté'; //Sujet du message 
IdMessage.Priority:=mpNormal; //Priorité du message
```

Thanks